# TikZ arrow tips not matching up

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to join two lines in TikZ and have a filled circle to denote the join. This is the code I have:

```
\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, shape border rotate=270, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum height=0.5em, minimum width=0.5em},
int/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=0.5em, minimum width=0.5em}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=0.75cm,>=latex']
\node [int] (int) {$\frac{1}{s}$};

\draw [draw,->] (int.east) -- ++(0: 2cm);
\draw [draw,*->] (int.east)++(0 :1cm) -- ++(90 :1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

It produces the following:

[image]

Why don't the two lines match up? How can I get them to match up?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrows (dot on the beginig of line is also arrow) newer prolong line length. So result of your code is expected. To solve your problem, you have two possibilities:

- make your line longer on the side with black circle
- draw this circle in connection coordinate

In the first case you can try with:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, shape border rotate=270, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum height=0.5em, minimum width=0.5em},
int/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=0.5em, minimum width=0.5em}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=0.75cm,>=latex']
\node [int] (int) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
\draw [draw,->] (int.east) -- ++(0: 2cm);
\draw [draw,*->,shorten <=-2.2pt] (int.east)++(0 :1cm) -- ++(90 :1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In the second case change image code to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=0.75cm,>=latex']
\node [int] (int) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
\draw [draw,->] (int.east) -- ++(0: 2cm);
\draw [draw,->,fill=black] (int.east)++(0 :1cm) -- ++(90 :1cm);
\draw [fill=black] (int.east)++(0 :1cm) circle (2.2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In both cases you will obtain the same result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with decorations! By the way, `\draw [draw]` is redundant because the command to draw is already included in the first command.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, fill=white, shape border rotate=270, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum height=0.5em, minimum width=0.5em},
    int/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=0.5em, minimum width=0.5em},
    mjoin/.style={decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0 with {\node[circle,fill, inner sep=1pt] {};}},postaction={decorate}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=0.75cm, -{Latex}]
\node [int] (int) {$\frac{1}{s}$};

\draw (int.east) -- ++(0: 2cm);
\draw [mjoin] (int.east)++(0 :1cm) -- ++(90 :1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The circle is set as arrow tip. Thus the tip end and not the middle of the circle tip is aligned with the starting point.

The following answer uses library `arrows.meta`, because it allows the configuration of the circle size. Then the radius is known and the line is prolonged by it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  int/.style={
    draw,
    fill=white,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=0.5em,
    minimum width=0.5em,
  },
}
\newdimen\joincircleradius
\setlength{\joincircleradius}{4pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=0.75cm,>=latex']
\node [int] (int) {$\frac{1}{s}$};

\draw [->] (int.east) -- ++(0: 3cm);
\draw [*->] (int.east)++(0 :1cm) -- ++(90 :1cm);
\draw [
    {Circle[length=\the\joincircleradius]}->,
    shorten <=-.5\joincircleradius,
] (int.east) ++(0: 2cm) -- ++(90: 1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]